# XSLT add missing node at specific location

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to insert a missing node to XML in case it is missing. For example, I want to add a `<Details>` node before CustomInformation node. I have written the below XSLT transformation but the attributes on the CostPlan node doesn't come up. Where am I going wrong?

Sample Data:

```
<CostPlan code="test" periodType="MONTHLY" >
    <Description/>
    <GroupingAttributes>
        <GroupingAttribute>cost_type_id</GroupingAttribute>
        <GroupingAttribute>transaction_class_id</GroupingAttribute>
        <GroupingAttribute>charge_code_id</GroupingAttribute>
    </GroupingAttributes>

    <CustomInformation>
        <ColumnValue name="pra">xyz</ColumnValue>
        <ColumnValue name="partition_code">abc</ColumnValue>
    </CustomInformation>
</CostPlan>
```

XSLT Transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CostPlan[not(Details)]">
         <xsl:variable name="elements-after" select="CustomInformation"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="* except $elements-after"/>
          <Details/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$elements-after"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<CostPlan> <!-- attributes missing compared to original  -->
   <Description/>
   <GroupingAttributes>
      <GroupingAttribute>cost_type_id</GroupingAttribute>
      <GroupingAttribute>transaction_class_id</GroupingAttribute>
      <GroupingAttribute>charge_code_id</GroupingAttribute>
   </GroupingAttributes>
   <Details/>
   <CustomInformation>
      <ColumnValue name="pra">xyz</ColumnValue>
      <ColumnValue name="partition_code">abc</ColumnValue>
   </CustomInformation>
</CostPlan>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your template matching `CostPlan[not(Details)]` does not handle attributes. Change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="* except $elements-after"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@* | * except $elements-after"/>
```

---

Note also that your stylesheet is tagged XSLT 1.0, but you are definitely using XSLT 2.0.

In XSLT 1.0 you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="CostPlan[not(Details)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | *[not(self::CustomInformation)]"/>
        <Details/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="CustomInformation"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the `$elements-after` variable is used only once and as such is redundant (in both versions).

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work perfectly.. any guidance on how I would do it in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2):

**Shorter and simpler**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CostPlan[not(Details)]/CustomInformation">
    <Details/>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way to do it! Thank you!